# Delete user in Google Apps Script - Fix "Resource Not Found userKey" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am creating a google apps script add-on that will allow us to add and delete users to our google apps domain. Certain information is entered into a google sheet (First name, last name, employee number, etc. etc.). Then, the person entering the users can select all the rows of users they would like to add.

Google apps script then creates a username and password based on their first and last name and enters them to our Google Apps domain among other things. This part works perfectly.

I am trying to write another function that will allow the person managing users to select the rows of users they would like to remove from our domain for whatever reason and click a "Delete Users" button. This will delete the users based on their email address in our system.

Here is my code:

```
function delUsers() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var i = range.getRow();
  var stop = range.getLastRow();

  while (i != stop + 1) {
    var email = sheet.getRange("C" + i).getValue();
    var user = String(email);
    AdminDirectory.Users.remove(user);
  }
};
```

You will see that the function loops through each row selected and gets the email address. It is in the format "First.Last@domain.com".

The problem is I keep getting the error "Resource Not Found userKey". Per suggestion from AbrahamB below, I made sure my userKey was a string as found in the GAS documentation. I used javascript's `typeof` to make sure of this.

The weird thing is upon further investigation, the user *is* actually being deleted, but the "Resource Not Found userKey" error is still being thrown.

Any help in explaining why this error is happening and how to fix it would be appreciated.

Comment: Not an expert on google apps, but does `userKey` need quotes around it? `"userKey": email`

Comment: Good thought, but that doesn't work. Google Apps Script is based on javascript and Object Literals do not use "" around the property name.

Comment: Where/how do you use userKey correctly in other places? if it's working the same way there it must be some small issue

Comment: Is it possible that the `email` var is not grabbing the correct object in your code? Have you tried `var_dump` on it to make sure it is accurate? If it's saying that the userKey is not found, and you only reference by the email var, than most likely the email var is incorrect.

Comment: var_dump does not exist in Javascript... However, I have ensured the output is a string and pushed the value of user and email to the console log in Google Apps Script and the output appeared as a string as it should be.

Answer (score 3):

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/delete

In this case, it expects a string, not a resource like you've created. As such, go ahead and do the following:

```
while (i != stop + 1) {
  var email = sheet.getRange("C" + i).getValue();
  var delete_user = AdminDirectory.Users.remove(email);
}
```

---

Regarding your updated question, this can happen if the user has been deleted already. However it is common practice to use a try/catch because if our script errors, it will stop completely. However, if it catches an error, you can log it and continue to iterate over the rest of the users.

```
try {
   AdminDirectory.Users.remove(user);
 } catch(e) {
   // if the script code throws an error,
   // do something with the error here
   // For example: Logger.log(e)
 }
```

Comment: Updated the answer.